# Blender for Virtual Reality

Tags: game-engine

How would you create a game with Blender that can be used by the HTC Vive? Is it even Possible? What are all of the steps for this to be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here you go: [Blender Room Scale VR Viewport on the HTC Vive](http://www.blendernation.com/2016/05/12/blender-room-scale-vr-viewport-htc-vive/)

Source can be found here:

https://github.com/cedeon/hmd_sdk_bridge/tree/cedeon-vive
https://github.com/cedeon/virtual_reality_viewport/tree/vivetest

For a real project you should consider using Unity3D and creating assets with Blender.

See also:

Blender VR
- https://blendervr.limsi.fr/doku.php