# VR visualizaitons

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

So there is the VR room scale thing, for blender. Is it possible to do this for a game created with blender? I would prefer not to use an outside program such as unity or unreal. So basically can you use the HMD to control the camera movement? And, Can you use the Vive's controllers as controllers? any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you 'can' but not natively or directly from a user point of view, as far as I know. You can theoretically do it through BGE python API using scripting. I am not much into programming so I can't confirm these facts, but I believe it has been done before.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57781/blender-for-virtual-reality/57797#57797

Comment: https://blendervr.limsi.fr/doku.php